# How can I make this VBA code that saves an Excel workbook work properly?

Tags: excel, vba

This code works for me and saves the workbook but not for someone else i send the file to.
It has to be saved as csv UTF8.

```
strSourceSheet = "Primis - Advertiser"
strFullname = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Primis Advertiser Import By " + C + ".csv"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, _
                  FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, _
                  CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

What could be the reason? Is there maybe an alternative way to save the woorkbook that I could try that also allows to specifiy the format?

Comment: Maybe that system supports UTF16? In the other system, manually try to save and see if you get that option? You may want to see [THIS](https://access-excel.tips/export-chinese-excel-to-csv/)

Comment: @SiddharthRout if anything its an older system, potentially running an office older than 2016